# How to fetch data from database as utf-8 CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What is this type of encode:

```
Káº¿t ná»‘i nÃ´ng nghiá»‡p Viá»‡t
```

It should be "Kết nối nông nghiệp Việt" but the view can't render utf-8, i don't know why. Please take a look at the picture below.

[image]

Database config:

```
    ORM::configure(array(
    'connection_string' => 'mysql:host='.$db_hostname.';dbname='.$db_name.'',
    'username' => ''.$db_username.'',
    'password' => ''.$db_password.''
));
    //ORM::configure('driver_options', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8')); #i tried uncomment this line but it's still not working
    //ORM::configure('error_mode', PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    //ORM::configure('return_result_sets', true);
    //ORM::configure('logging', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit **Collation** type column to :`utf8mb4_unicode_ci`